# fetching tweets using rest_api in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dataset

I am trying to get 10 tweets. I set the count to 5 and apply "for it in range(2)". This means it should retrieve not more then 10 tweets. But, here it is giving me 15 tweets  in which tweets id's of tweets 1 to 5 are appearing twice.

```
alltweet=[]
def rest_query_ex3():
            query = "road"
                    geo = "42.6525,-73.7572,9mi"
                    MAX_ID = None
                    for it in range(2):  # should Retrieve up to 10 tweets
                      tweets = myApi.search(q=query, geocode=geo, count=5, max_id=MAX_ID)
                      if tweets:
                        MAX_ID= tweets[-1].id
                        alltweet.extend(tweets)
                        for pk in alltweet:
                          print pk.id


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        rest_query_ex3()
```

in this image some tweets id's are repeating and giving me more then 10 tweets. Can someone please help me on this using rest_api in python
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prceL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `print` statement

```
for pk in alltweet:
                      print pk.id
```

First time in the `loop` it will print `5` tweets.

Next time it `prints` (`5 + 5`) tweets.

So this `prints` total `15` tweets.

Maybe you would like to move the `print` `loop` out of the other `for` `loop` like:

```
 for it in range(2):  # should Retrieve up to 10 tweets
                      tweets = myApi.search(q=query, geocode=geo, count=5, max_id=MAX_ID)
                      if tweets:
                        MAX_ID= tweets[-1].id
                        alltweet.extend(tweets)
 for pk in alltweet:
     print pk.id
```

Comment: @mithleshgupta can you please in my another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399741/rest-api-using-tweets-are-not-dumping-into-file-in-python