# rest_api using tweets are not dumping into file in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, dataset

according to this code a file should be with 5000 tweets in this. But nothing is going into file and shows json serialization error.

here is the code

```
alltweet=[]
def rest_query_ex3():
    MAX_ID = None
    query = "(disease OR illness OR sickness)"
    file=open("tweetfile.txt", "a+")
    for it in range(50):
     tweets = myApi.search(q=query, count=100, max_id=MAX_ID)
     if tweets:
         MAX_ID = tweets[-1].id
         alltweet.extend(tweets)
    for tweet in alltweet:
        s=[tweet.text, tweet.id]
        file.write(json.dumps(s))
    file.close()
```

Comment: post the full error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/datamining/hw3/datafetch.py", line 40, in <module>
    rest_query_ex3()
  File "E:/datamining/hw3/datafetch.py", line 36, in rest_query_ex3
    file.write(json.dumps(tweet))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)

Comment: rest of the error id here

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Comment: i got the solution but i am curious to know what you suggest for the same error

Comment: This is not the exception corresponding to the above program
You exception has `file.write(json.dumps(tweet))`. but your program has
        `s=[tweet.text, tweet.id]
        file.write(json.dumps(s))`

Comment: I replaced s=[tweet.text, tweet.id] file.write(json.dumps(s)) this code with  file.write(json.dumps(tweet)) ...still it give the same error

Comment: This is because you by default you can serialize only string, integer,boolean, dictionary or list . Not all objects by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alltweet=[]

def rest_query_ex3():
    MAX_ID = None
    geo = "42.6525,-73.7572,200mi"
    query = "(disease)"
    file =open("tweetfile.txt", "a+")
    for it in range(1):
     tweets = myApi.search(q=query, geocode=geo, count=5, max_id=MAX_ID)
     if tweets:
         MAX_ID = tweets[-1].id
         alltweet.extend(tweets)
         #print type(alltweet)   #this is list type object
    for tweet in alltweet:
        file.write(json.dumps(tweet._json)) 
#converting into string remove sthe serializable error without adding a new class
        file.write('\n\n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest_query_ex3()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alltweet=[]

def rest_query_ex3():
    MAX_ID = None
    geo = "42.6525,-73.7572,200mi"
    query = "(disease)"
    file =open("tweetfile.txt", "a+")
    for it in range(1):
     tweets = myApi.search(q=query, geocode=geo, count=5, max_id=MAX_ID)
     if tweets:
         MAX_ID = tweets[-1].id
         alltweet.extend(tweets)
         #print type(alltweet)   #this is list type object
    for tweet in alltweet:
        file.write(json.dumps(str(tweet))) 
#converting into string remove sthe serializable error without adding a new class
        file.write('\n\n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest_query_ex3()
```